# Renaming all duplicate files in directory tree to have unique names

Tags: python, operating-system, subdirectory, batch-rename, file-management

I have a directory tree which contains a bunch of files with the same name, which I'd like to rename with unique names. It looks something like this:

```
root
    folder1
        a
        b
        c
    folder2
        a
        c
        d
        folder3
            a
            b
            c
```

I'd like to add a number to the end of the filenames to give them all unique names. I'd like for it to look something like this near the end.

```
root
    folder1
        a1
        b1
        c1
    folder2
        a2
        c2
        d
        folder3
            a3
            b2
            c3
```

I have been messing around with os.walk and have managed to create a list of all filenames of which there exist more than one. It feels like I'm nearing a solution, but I just can't grasp it ... Need to write a clever for loop, I suppose. I am feeling a bit stuck atm. Does anyone have a suggestion or solution to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to rename all files in all subdirectories as shown in your sample.
The code will find all files and keep track of which name has occurred earlier and what should be the number appended.

```
import os

path = '<INSERT PATH>'
file_dict = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(name)
        new_name = file_name + str(file_dict.get(name, '')) + file_ext
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, name), os.path.join(root, new_name))
        if name not in file_dict:
            file_dict[name] = 0
        file_dict[name] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use module `Path` to accomplish that straightforward:

```
from pathlib import Path
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import groupby

rootdir = Path('root').resolve()

# Build file list
filenames = sorted([(file.name, file)
                        for file in rootdir.glob('**/*')
                        if file.is_file()], key=itemgetter(0)

# Group by filename and rename files
for k, g in groupby(filenames, key=itemgetter(0)):
    for i, (_, src) in enumerate(g, 1):
        dest = src.parent / f"{src.stem}{i}{src.suffix}"
        print(f"Moved '{src}' -> '{dest}'")
        src.rename(dest)
```